# libxls: xls_open() crash with long path in C

Tags: c, xls

According of the location of my exe, if the path is too long (117 characters for example), my software crashes.

Below is example of my code:

```
Book_t *l_WBook_Ptr;
Sheet_t *l_WSheet_Ptr;
Row_t   *l_Row_Ptr;
BYTE* l_Cell;   

printf("\ntest path: %s\n",argv_Ptr[1]);
printf("xls open\n");

l_WBook_Ptr = xls_open(argv_Ptr[1], "ASCII");

if(l_WBook_Ptr != NULL)
{
   printf("xls get work sheet\n");

   l_WSheet_Ptr = xls_getWorkSheet(l_WBook_Ptr, 0);

    if(l_WSheet_Ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("xls parse work sheet\n");
        xls_parseWorkSheet(l_WSheet_Ptr);

        /*Get the content of cell*/
        l_Row_Ptr = &l_WSheet_Ptr->rows.row[1];

        l_Cell = l_Row_Ptr->cells.cell[0].str;

        printf("The content of cell: %s\n",l_Cell);

        printf("xls_close_WS\n");
        xls_close_WS(l_WSheet_Ptr);

    } 
    else
    {
        printf("\nerror\n");
    }
    printf("xls close\n");
    xls_close(l_WBook_Ptr); 
}
else
{
    printf("\nerror\n");
}
return 0;
```

I have determined that the problem appears when I call the function `xls_open`.

When my program is launched from the command line or a .bat, it crashes. Then if it launches with the debugger, it works fine. And then it works from the command line !!

Like there would be a windows/lib problem !!

Note: I use xls lib to read the content of cell

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the Guidelines in the Help Center on asking questions on the site. Your question is unclear and does not provide enough information. I'm going to try to "translate" some of your French terms into English, which may help. But you need to provide the code that's causing the problem and a concrete example of when/how your program crashes. Also, you need all the correct TAGS. XLS is insufficient. You mention "C language" in the subject. Is this C? C++? C#? You need to be very specific, otherwise no one will see your question who can help you!

Comment: is edited now, thanks

Comment: How do you launch your program ? You have to give it 1 argument, and that argument needs to be an existing file (you should change your code so you check that it actually was passed 1 argument, and you should check that xls_open() suceeds.

Comment: i give it the argument when i lunch the command line or .bat  there is the content of my arg
argv_Ptr[1] = "C:\test\conftool\verification\Workspace\exe_test\xls_input\strCell.xls";

Comment: When i put .exe in "C:\Users\adminDesktop.work\Desktop\soft_779980_sw-mfolder.working\xls_code_bug\xls_file_code_block\xlsFileToRead\bin\Debug" it does'nt worke but when i put in "C:\Users\adminDesktop.work\Desktop\soft_779980_sw-mfolder.working\xls_code_bug\xls_file_code_block\xlsFileToRead\bin\Debugg" it is work fine !!! i changed the name of last folder (add one character)